# Will a template bool be optimized out by the compiler?

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a linked-list class and I've just written a set of functions to make it work with range-based for. To use the same class template for the forward iterator (such as you get with begin() ) as the reverse iterator (such as you get with rbegin() ), I added a bool to the template arguments. during increment or decrement, the bool is checked one time. Will it be optimized away by the compiler or will the check happen at runtime?

```
template< typename TYPE >
template< typename LINKTYPE, typename LINK, const bool REVERSE >
LinkList<TYPE>::IteratorBase<LINKTYPE, LINK, REVERSE> LinkList<TYPE>::IteratorBase<LINKTYPE, LINK, REVERSE>::operator++( int ) {
    Link<TYPE> *old = cur;

    if ( cur ) {
        cur = REVERSE ? cur->GetPrevious() : cur->GetNext();
        return old;
    }

    cur = nullptr;
    return old;
}
```

here is a more complete excerpt of the code: http://pastebin.com/vv7Wgm9T

Comment: Depends on the compiler, but probably. If you are really worried about it, you should specialize it rather than use it the way you are.

Comment: I wanted to specialize, but in my research I've discovered that you cannot partially specialize methods without specializing an entire class. I'd like to not have a bunch of copypasta.

Comment: The way I get around this is inheritance, with the child being specialized, but this is also when I start thinking that I've made my design way too damn complicated. Honestly, I'd say only worry about it if your code ends up too slow. You can look at the assembly yourself to see if your compiler and settings eliminate the conditional.

Comment: Even if the check happens on run time, it is probably really fast thanks to branch prediction. You should just measure it.

Comment: I was just curious if it was a well-established rule to optimize this, I'm not terribly worried about it. I might examine the assembly but it'll take an ASM refresher and some coffee. What is Branch Prediction? (to google, I go!)

Comment: While I appreciate that in terms of 'standardese', people have to say this isn't guaranteed to be optimised - it's a template parameter, i.e. a compile-time constant, so any compiler that didn't optimise this away immediately under non-debug settings wouldn't be worth the time of day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the C++ standard about when to perform an optimization like this, so it's strictly compiler-specific. Thus the only way to find out for sure is to either consult your compiler's documentation or to compile the code and look at the disassembly. Most likely it will be optimized away but there are no guarantees as to that behavior.

Comment: In particular, the code must be parsed regardless of any optimization. You can't have errors in there.